# Connected to remote VPN, now can't connect to server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, connection

So I'm not the most tech savvy, but have a VPS I connect to via IP and putty key. I went ahead and followed [this tutorial](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/guides/linux/linux/linux-installing-openvpn-through-the-terminal) to installing and using OpenVPN through the linux terminal, but after doing so it terminated the connection and I can't log back in for some reason. Anyone able to help?

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/vTQsZtcA) the last bit of log I grabbed before closing the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I expect your vpn connection to manipulate your default routing so that every packet uses the vpn route.  In the end you lose any previous established connection. There should be two ways around this:

1. Connect to your Server after having established the vpn connection. Disadvantage: As soon as you terminate your vpn connection you have to reestablish the connection to your server.
2. Modify your routing rules. Create a rule that forces routing to your server outside the vpn connection. To do so you need to know the ip of your server and the ip and/or the network interface name of your ethernet card.

---

2.1. Type in `ip a` in terminal to find out your interface names and ip addresses.

```
ip a
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:1d:cd:37:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.59/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic enp3s0
       valid_lft 863431sec preferred_lft 863431sec
3: enp4s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:1d:cd:37:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c4:0d:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In the case of this example the interface name we are looking for is enp3s0. The ip it has been assigned to is 192.168.178.59.

2.2. Create a route to your server. Lets say your server has the IP 194.57.84.36 than you have to write the following rule: `sudo ip route add 192.57.84.36 via 192.168.178.59 dev enp3s0`

2.3. Check your routing table with `ip route`

Before modification:

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp3s0  proto static  metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.59  metric 100
```

after modification

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp3s0  proto static  metric 100 
192.57.84.36 via 192.168.178.59 dev enp3s0 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.59  metric 100
```

Note: The rule will be deleted after reboot.

Comment: Edit: Thanks for the thought out answer! I only have "Lo" and "Ens3" options though, with the default already set to ens3. How would I add enp3s0 to the list?

Comment: Edit your question and add your output of 'ip a'